# What is the fastest way to get multiple copies of a tree in python?

Tags: python, tree, copy

In my python program I need multiple copies of a tree. Initially, I use deepcopy from the copy module, which turns out to be very slow. Then I write my own code to copy a tree, the code traverses the tree being copied and create a new node at each node being visited. Then
I call this subroutines multiple times to get multiple copies. This solution is much faster (~40 times faster) than deepcopy.

Solution 2: Then I think, traversing a tree needs time T, make n copies, the time required is nT; but if I create n new nodes for each node being copied, I only need to traverse the tree being copied once, although at each node, you copy multiple nodes. Will this be faster? The result turns out to be: not much.

Still the copy operation is the bottleneck of my program. Is there any faster way to do that? Thanks! 
Stats -- using custom copy_tree function;

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   10.406   10.406 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002   10.406   10.406 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1431(algorithm1)
       26    0.005    0.000    4.602    0.177 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1310(engage)
     1342    0.005    0.000    4.208    0.003 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:594(__call__)
     1342    0.007    0.000    4.203    0.003 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:208(remotecall)
     1342    0.017    0.000    3.992    0.003 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:238(asyncreturn)
     1342    0.005    0.000    3.972    0.003 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:279(getresponse)
     1342    0.033    0.000    3.961    0.003 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:295(_getresponse)
   411/26    0.202    0.000    3.930    0.151 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1227(NodeEngage)
     1338    0.014    0.000    3.909    0.003 C:\Python27\lib\threading.py:235(wait)
     5356    3.877    0.001    3.877    0.001 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
       27    0.001    0.000    3.798    0.141 C:\Python27\sdk.py:888(pick_best_group)
      378    0.003    0.000    3.797    0.010 C:\Python27\sdk.py:862(group_info)
46947/378    0.155    0.000    3.786    0.010 C:\Python27\sdk.py:833(core_possibilities)
    27490    0.114    0.000    3.547    0.000 C:\Python27\sdk.py:779(find_cores)
    46569    1.046    0.000    3.424    0.000 C:\Python27\sdk.py:798(find_a_true_core)
   280274    0.873    0.000    1.464    0.000 C:\Python27\sdk.py:213(next)
       27    0.002    0.000    1.393    0.052 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1008(s)
    28196    0.016    0.000    1.070    0.000 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1000(copy_tree)
```

.............................Compare with deepcopy approach

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  191.193  191.193 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002  191.193  191.193 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1431(algorithm1)
       26    0.006    0.000  185.611    7.139 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1310(engage)
   411/26    1.200    0.003  185.013    7.116 C:\Python27\sdk.py:1227(NodeEngage)
30033397/28196   56.608    0.000  177.885    0.006 C:\Python27\lib\copy.py:145(deepcopy)
3340177/28196   15.354    0.000  177.741    0.006 C:\Python27\lib\copy.py:283(_deepcopy_inst)
6680354/28196   23.276    0.000  177.261    0.006 C:\Python27\lib\copy.py:253(_deepcopy_dict)
3340177/150307   22.345    0.000  171.525    0.001 C:\Python27\lib\copy.py:234(_deepcopy_tuple)
 13360708   23.793    0.000   23.793    0.000 {hasattr}
 13614747   12.483    0.000   15.349    0.000 C:\Python27\lib\copy.py:267(_keep_alive)
     1342    0.005    0.000    7.281    0.005 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:594(__call__)
     1342    0.008    0.000    7.276    0.005 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:208(remotecall)
     1342    0.019    0.000    7.039    0.005 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:238(asyncreturn)
     1342    0.005    0.000    7.018    0.005 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:279(getresponse)
     1342    0.035    0.000    7.006    0.005 C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py:295(_getresponse)
 43649486    6.971    0.000    6.971    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
     1341    0.015    0.000    6.950    0.005 C:\Python27\lib\threading.py:235(wait)
     5365    6.917    0.001    6.917    0.001 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
  6680354    5.325    0.000    5.325    0.000 {method 'iteritems' of 'dict' objects}
 57037048    4.854    0.000    4.854    0.000 {id}
```

@ThomasH: this is the copy function, which is very simple and custom. See my comment to Ross for the content of tree nodes

```
def r_copy_tree(node_to_copy, dad_info):
    new_node = node(dad_info)

    for (a,son_to_copy) in node_to_copy.sons.items():
        new_node.sons[a]=r_copy_tree(son_to_copy,(new_node,a))

    return new_node

def copy_tree(root):
    return r_copy_tree(root,(None,None))
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple copies of a tree, by the way?

Comment: They will be mounted on a bigger tree.

Comment: +1 Very good topic, thanks for bringing it up. - Why do you think copying is still the bottleneck, even with your custom copy_tree? Your stats show it at about 10% of the overall run time. Can you show the implementation of copy_tree?

Comment: Also, what are the contents of the tree?

Comment: Oh, This stat is just to show the difference between copy_tree and deepcopy on a simpler problem in which there is not much copy to do. But if my algorithm is fed with massive trees, copy_tree will account for 70% of run time.

Comment: @Ross: The tree is actually simple. Each node holds not much information: 1. A dictionary whose keys hold arc information and the values are (references to) children nodes, 2. Reference to its parent node, and the info of the arc by which its parent connect this node. I need this to trace back to ancestors. The tree size is also a problem for me. I think I need at most 20M nodes in a tree, which seems to just beyond the 2G memory limit. So occasionally memoryErr is raised.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to improve performance you should almost always start with [profiling](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) data and then optimize based on what you see there.  Start by using [`cProfile.run`](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#cProfile.run) to run your top-level tree copy code, then use [`pstats.Stats`](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats) class to inspect the profiling data and see where you should really focus your optimization.  I recommend starting by [sorting your stats](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.sort_stats) by `cumulative` time.

Comment: I am already using it. That is why I know it is the bottleneck. Thanks,anyway.

Comment: That's a good thing to mention in your question.  Please also include your top print_stats output when sorted by cumulative time.  Deepcopy does many things and the hotspot might be something particular in there.